# Download mp3 file, save to disk, and read it as a URL

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know there is allot of questions already about saving to disk, but nun of them helped me.

In my app, i'm using a player that must read from a url, and this url mustn't be by stream, i mean, it must be on the device. (because i'm making special effects on the audio, and streaming will not work for that).

So i'm downloading the file like so:

```
      AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation;
   operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //Secusses

    NSData *resposeObject = responseObject;

       NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NS  UserDomainMask, YES);
         NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.mp3"];
        [responseObject writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];


     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          //Fail;
     }];
```

And after i download it, i need to play in as a url, in this method:

```
   self.audioMusicPlayer = [AEAudioFilePlayer audioFilePlayerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someFile]      audioController:_audioController error:&error];
```

I'm struggling with understanding how is my data, can be saved as a mp3 file, and play it after, as a url that is on disk..

I manage to play a file that is in my app without downloading, and it looks like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
        self.audioMusicPlayer = [AEAudioFilePlayer audioFilePlayerWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]    URLForResource:@"RegevHodBetelemOhavim" withExtension:@"mp3"] audioController:_audioController     error:&error];
```

**EDIT**

This is the way i'm trying to play in, and its not working

```
     NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

         NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",    documentsDirectory,@"filename.mp3"];


    /*
      NSError *error = nil;
       self.audioMusicPlayer = [AEAudioFilePlayer audioFilePlayerWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]    URLForResource:@"RegevHodBetelemOhavim" withExtension:@"mp3"] audioController:_audioController    error:&error];
       */

       NSError *error = nil;
       self.audioMusicPlayer = [AEAudioFilePlayer audioFilePlayerWithURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:filePath] audioController:_audioController error:&error];
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is your code working or are you inquiring on how the 'behind the scenes mechanics' work?

Comment: What is the problem?? The download part? or the player part? Can you play the downloaded file with another player?

Comment: Yes, no player has a initWithUrl can read this url, it crushes every time

Comment: What if you replace [NSURL URLWithString:filePath] by [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] ? By the way, you should also create filePath with [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.mp3"] instead of manually, it's a better way to deal with paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help, the code was perfectly fine, the was trying to run is on the simulator for some unknown reason.... Sorry! and thanks again.